# How can I do this search&replace with vim?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a text file containing these lines:

options[15]=new Option("text1","25");

options[16]=new Option("text2","23");

options[17]=new Option("text3","12");

(and more...)

How can I replace each line with text# ?.for example first line should be replaced by text1, second line with text2,etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `:h /\(`

```
%s/\Voptions[\d\+]=new Option("\(text\d\+\)","\d\+");/\1/g
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to `:s` and using a macro, I sometimes find `:normal` to be very pleasant.

```
%norm df"f"d$
```

We can short this up but using `;` motion which will repeat the `f"` motion and use `D` which is the same as `d$`

```
%norm df";D
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you already have them in the source. Assuming that you have the lines like this:

    options[15]=new Option("text#","25");

...

And you want to change to this: 
    options[15]=new Option("text15","25");

...

Here is what you do:
change the first line to text1
yank "text1"

```
create a macro (qq)
/text
dw
p
ctrl+a
b
vwly
q
```

Then if you have 25 lines: do 23@q

23 invocations of the macro since you have done the first two manually.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work also:

```
:%s/^.\{-}\(".\{-}"\).*/\1
```

The part `^.\{-}` match everything till the group `\(".\{-}"\)`, what is the target text to keep, finally `\1` do the replacement.